# Do two isomorphic normal subgroups yield the same quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

Let $G$ be a group with normal subgroups $H\cong K$, then $G/H\cong G/K$ is not true in general.
This question was being discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40881/isomorphic-quotients-by-isomorphic-normal-subgroups) already. But I don't really understand why it's gotten so complicated there. Can't we just take $H=2\mathbb Z$ and $K=3\mathbb Z$ for $G=\mathbb Z$?

Comment: The question you're linking also gives a simple counter example...but it also goes way further into this matter. That is why, apparently, things get much  messier there than simply giving a counter example. Read carefully the question there.

Comment: Yes. This doesn't answer my question though.

Comment: Since the question over there was about finite groups, I don't see how your example answers it.

Comment: @bof Now you're just trying to misunderstand me on purpose. Just read the first sentence again.

Comment: No, I must be misunderstanding you, but I'm not doing it on purpose. You linked to a question about finite groups, and you say you don't understand why it's so complicated there, and give an example with $G=\mathbb Z$. Call me dumbo, but I don't get it.

Comment: Just because noone has said it yet: Yes, your counter-example *does* answer the question you ask.

Comment: @user1729 Thank you. That's all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest example that I was able to think of. Take $G=S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$. Let $H_1=\langle(1\ \ 2\ \ 3)\rangle\times\{0\}$ and let $H_2=\{e\}\times\mathbb{Z}_3$. Then $H_1\simeq H_2$, $G/H_1\simeq\mathbb{Z}_6$, and $G/H_2\simeq S_3$. Of course, $\mathbb{Z}_6\not\simeq S_3$.

Comment: You could also use two copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ (giving you respective quotients $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your counter-example does answer the question you ask.

The question you link to asks a more technical question, involving automorphisms. That is why the discussion there is so much more complicated. Also, your counter-example does not answer the question there because it is assuming that the group $G$ is finite (and clearly $G\cong \mathbb{Z}$ is infinite!).