# Definition of subobject and a proof of Schur's lemma in abelian categories

Tags: proof-writing, category-theory, definition, abelian-categories

$\require{AMScd}$In [*Tensor Categories*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/egnobookfinal.pdf) by *Etingof et al*, a subobject $B$ of $A$ is not defined via isomorphism classes of monomorphisms. Rather, it is stated that a monomorphism $B \hookrightarrow A$ makes $B$ a subobject.

My first problem becomes now apparent:

- They define a simple object $X$ to be an object that has only $0$ and itself as subobject. This seems already problematic to me, because isomorphisms break this definition. That is, if two objects $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic, then they will not be *simple* using this definition. Defining *simple object* (or rather *subobject*) via isomorphism classes would get rid of this.

Now we want to prove **Schur's Lemma** (p 5), which is stated as

> Let $X, Y$ be simple objects. Then any nonzero morphism $f\in\mathrm{Hom}[X,Y]$ is an isomorphism.

So far, my proof is as follows:

> We have the canonical decomposition (unlabeled arrows are identities)
>
> $$\begin{CD} K @>\ker f>>X @>\mathrm{coker }\ker f>> \mathrm{Im}(f) @>\ker\mathrm{coker } f>> Y @>\mathrm{coker }f>> C\\
> @. @VVV  @. @AAA\\
> @. X @>f>>Y @>>>Y
> \end{CD}$$
>   Kernels are monic, so $K$ is either 0 or $X$, since $X$ is simple. It can't be $X$, since $f$ is supposed to be nonzero. But this means that $f$ is monic, so $\mathrm{Im}(f)=X$, $f= \ker \mathrm{coker } f$, and $\mathrm{coker }\ker f = \mathrm{id}_X$.
>
> Now we get the problem again: It also implies that $X$ is a subobject of $Y$, which contradicts either the definition or the supposition.

My second problem is

- What to do now? Can the proof be salvaged yet?

So, in summary:

1. Is the definition sound?
2. If the answer to 1. is "Yes", then how to complete the proof? (it is clear that a definition using isomorphism classes would make the proof a lot easier)

Comment: So $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$

Comment: Why should that follow immediately?

Comment: Since X is a nonzero subobject of Y and Y is simple

Comment: This book is pretty good, thank you for introducing it to me.

Comment: No, in our definition, this would actually imply that $X$ is equal to $Y$. Not isomorphic, but equal. That is a **huge** difference. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I think the definition should be understood as "isomorphism classes" rather than "monomorphism". Or the definition of simple object should include a "up to isomorphism" somewhere.

Comment: A subobject of $A$ is a monomorphism $B\to A$ or an isomorphism class of monos into $A$, but it should definitely not be: an object $B$, such that there *exists* a mono $B\to A$. After all, "subobject" should be a generalization of e.g. subgroups, but in this fashion you would be treating isomorphic (as groups) subgroups as the same, which you [shouldn't](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40763/isomorphic-quotient-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1). That's also not what is stated in the book.

Comment: The difference between subobjects as monos and as isomorphism classes of monos is definitely not essential (replacing isomorphy with equality or vice versa).

Comment: @StefanPerko: Hm, I certainly did not write that I consider a subobject to be an object s.t. $\exists$ a mono. In fact, I pretty much wrote down Definition 1.3.5 from the book: "An object *together* with a monomorphism" (I feel that definition does make it seem like a property of an object).  I don't understand your last remark, why is the difference negligible? Thanks

Comment: Now I think the problem of me not being able to complete the proof is that the canonical decomposition is unique up to unique isomorphism (i.e. universal property of image/coimage).

Comment: @JoBe That is how I understood your definition. If it is just me, then forget I said anything. - I can't think of any good reason why the difference is not negligible (we are replacing a thin category with a skeleton thereof; these categories are equivalent, so I consider them "the same")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since in category theory everything is defined up to isomorphism I think that the authors of the book meant that

> A simple object $X$ is an object whose subobjects, up to isomorphism, are just $0$ and $X$ itself.

About the second question I do not see any problem: you have proven so far that $X$, or to be exact $f \colon X \to Y$ is a subobject of $Y$, now since $Y$ is simple either $X$ is (isomorphic to) $0$ or it is (isomorphic to) $Y$. Since by hypothesis $f$ is not the null morphism clearly $X$ is not $0$ hence the thesis easily follows.