# Given two isomorphic subgroups of a finite abelian group with the same number of minimal generators, are the quotients isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group.

We know that the least size of a minimal generating set of a proper nontrivial subgroup $H \leqslant G$  might be the same  as $G$, for example ($\Bbb Z_6 \cong   \Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_2  $ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$, and both $\Bbb Z_6$ and $\Bbb Z_2$ can be generated by $1$ element).
Also, in general, given two isomorphic subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ of $G$, it is not necessarily true that $G/H_1$ and $G/H_2$ are isomorphic ([Isomorphic quotient groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40763/976076)).

However, if the least size of a minimal generating set of each $H_i$
is the same as that of $G$, and $H_1 \cong H_2$, does this implies that $G/H_1 \cong G/H_2$?

Comment: Do you really mean "same number of minimal generating sets", or do you mean "the least size of a minimal generating set of $H_i$ is the same as that of $G$"?

Comment: (The reason I ask is that $\mathbb{Z}_6$ has $1$ as the smallest size of a minimal generating set, but has four "minimal generating sets", namely $\{1\}$, $\{5\}$, $\{2,3\}$,  and $\{3,4\}$).

Comment: yes, @ArturoMagidin, thank you!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen unfortunately  $\Bbb Z_3 $ and $\Bbb Z_2  $ are not isomorphic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two subgroups isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_4$ in $C_4 \times C_8$ with non-isomorphic quotient groups.